# Extract multiply imputed datasets into a list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, iteration, r-mice

I am performing multiple imputation on my data with the mice package and want to extract the results as a list of data frames. This is what I have tried, using `map` and `mice::complete`.

```
library(mice)

m = 2
data <- airquality[1:30,]
imp <- mice(data, seed = 123, m, print = F) #impute data
imp_list_df <- map(1:m, function(x) complete(imp, x))
```

I would like the classes of each object to be as follows:

```
> class(imp_list_df)
[1] "list"
> class(imp_list_df[1])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Currently `class(imp_list_df[1])` returns `"list"`. Any thoughts on functions I can use instead of map to return a list of data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `list` of data.frames.

```
str(imp_list_df)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   30 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ Ozone  : int [1:30] 41 36 12 18 6 28 23 19 8 30 ...
  ..$ Solar.R: int [1:30] 190 118 149 313 8 313 299 99 19 194 ...
  ..$ Wind   : num [1:30] 7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
  ..$ Temp   : int [1:30] 67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
  ..$ Month  : int [1:30] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ Day    : int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   30 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ Ozone  : int [1:30] 41 36 12 18 18 28 23 19 8 16 ...
  ..$ Solar.R: int [1:30] 190 118 149 313 66 307 299 99 19 194 ...
  ..$ Wind   : num [1:30] 7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
  ..$ Temp   : int [1:30] 67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
  ..$ Month  : int [1:30] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ Day    : int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The proper way to extract a `list` is with `[[`

```
class(imp_list_df[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"
```

When we do extraction with `[`, it still returns a `list` i.e. using `[1]`, it extracts as a `list` of `length` 1 and the element is a `data.frame`

```
> str(imp_list_df[1])
List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   30 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ Ozone  : int [1:30] 41 36 12 18 6 28 23 19 8 30 ...
  ..$ Solar.R: int [1:30] 190 118 149 313 8 313 299 99 19 194 ...
  ..$ Wind   : num [1:30] 7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
  ..$ Temp   : int [1:30] 67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
  ..$ Month  : int [1:30] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ Day    : int [1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> str(imp_list_df[[1]])
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 6 28 23 19 8 30 ...
 $ Solar.R: int  190 118 149 313 8 313 299 99 19 194 ...
 $ Wind   : num  7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
 $ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
 $ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Also, to check the `class` of each element at once, use `sapply/lapply`

```
sapply(imp_list_df, class)
[1] "data.frame" "data.frame"
```